# const err = new MongooseError(message); MongooseError: Operation `fruits.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.set('strictQuery', false);
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/fruitsDB", {useNewUrlParser: true});


const fruitSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
  name:String,
  rating: Number,
  review: String
});

const Fruit = mongoose.model("Fruit", fruitSchema);

const fruit = new Fruit ({
  name: "Apple",
  rating: 7,
  review: "Pretty good"
});

fruit.save();
```

This is my code.

```
$ node app.js 
C:\Users\Aman\Desktop\fruitsProj\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:175
          const err = new MongooseError(message);
                      ^

MongooseError: Operation `fruits.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Aman\Desktop\fruitsProj\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:175:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7)
```

Node.js v18.14.0

This is the error

I am following an online course and currently facing an error.
Please help me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/fruitsDB', {useNewUrlParser:true});

const Fruit = mongoose.model("Fruit",{
  name: String,
  rating: Number,
  review: String});


const Fruit = mongoose.model("Fruit", fruitSchema);

const fruit = new Fruit({
  name: "Apple",
  rating: 7, 
  review: "Pretty good"
});

fruit.save().then(() => console.log('Data Save Successful!'));
```

**Hope this code will work for you.**

**And also you may have did one error in insertOne() function, that's why its throwing an error in the console.
You must use the this format while using insertOne() function:-**

```
modelName.insertOne(callback(req, res){
{condition},
{query},
callback(err)
});
```

**(As per your code, here "modelName" is "Fruit")**

**Upvote if this answer looks useful to you :)**

Comment: No, its still not working. My mongoDB version is 4.0

Comment: Can you provide the whole code block?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/fruitsDB', {
  useNewUrlParser: true
});

const fruitSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  rating: Number,
  review: String
});

const Fruit = mongoose.model("Fruit", fruitSchema);

const fruit = new Fruit({
  name: "Apple",
  rating: 7,
  review: "Pretty good"
});

fruit.save().then(() => console.log('Data Save Successful!'));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I am also doing same online course and facing same error.

//! Use 127.0.0.1 instead localhost

mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/fruitsDB", { useNewUrlParser: true })

You can connect to MongoDB with the mongoose.connect() method. mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/myapp'); This is the minimum needed to connect the myapp database running locally on the default port (27017). For local MongoDB databases, we recommend using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing that course and used that code to make it work, after hours trying to understand what was going on. Thanks Ashish!

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/fruitsDB', { useNewUrlParser: true });
        
const fruitSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  rating: Number,
  review: String,
});
        
const Fruit = mongoose.model("Fruit", fruitSchema);
        
const fruit = new Fruit({
  name: "Apple",
  rating: 7,
  review: "Pretty good"
});
        
// fruit.save().then(() => console.log('Data Save Successful!'));
        
const personSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
  name: String,
  age: Number,
});
        
const Person = mongoose.model("Person", personSchema);
        
const person = new Person({
  name: "Juliana",
  age: 36,
});
        
person.save().then(() => console.log('Data Save Successful!'));
```